# Why is ctor with default argument std::initializer_list unavailable (VS2019)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I can't quite figure out why this code doesn't compile on Visual Studio 2019 (16.8.3):

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct Foo
{
    Foo(std::initializer_list<int> = {});
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
}

Foo::Foo(std::initializer_list<int>) {}
```

It gives me this error:

> C2512: "Foo": no appropriate default constructor available

Is this a compiler bug or am I missing something here?
Note that I've checked and this does compile on GCC 10.1

If you change the forward declaration of the constructor to an immediate definition the code compiles without errors:

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct Foo
{
    Foo(std::initializer_list<int> = {}) {}
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
}
```

Comment: Huh, that's strange. Compiles fine on VS-2017?

Comment: Compiles fine with clang 11.0.0. And compiles fine with microsofts `cl` (The one that uses visual studio) version 19.26.28806

Comment: Works on my VS2019, version 16.8.2.

Comment: Be sure that your project settings say to use c++17 or latest, vc defaults to c++14 and even then there were a lot more problems than more recent language variants.

Comment: I've tried setting it to c++17 and latest and it still doesn't compile. My cl.exe version is 19.28.29335, it's kind of weird that it compiles on the same VS version for @Blastfurnace and not for me

Comment: Works for me in VS 16.8.3 (19.28.29335). Check you're compiling the file you think you're compiling.

Comment: wow, that's bizarre

Comment: ok, I'm sorry, the code I was compiling had a forward declaration of ctor and the code I originally posted had an empty definition of ctor (which shouldn't matter in this context). Can you check if the edited version compiles?

Comment: Now it doesn't.

Comment: I'm slightly surprised it's not a linker error, but only slightly. VS blurs the lines between compilation and linking slightly, if everything you're doing is in one translation unit. (In reality, there were no lines to blur; it's GCC and Clang that add these lines.) I think this is completely expected.

Comment: but even with the definition somewhere else it doesn't compile

Comment: If you still get a build error when the definition is provided in another TU, then we have a problem, and you should report it to Microsoft.

Comment: Yep, that's a bug; doesn't happen with an `int` arg

Comment: Oh wow, you don't even need a separate TU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is a compiler bug here.**

It shouldn't be failing compilation just because the constructor's definition isn't available in the same translation unit (providing it in another one, or even providing it underneath `main`, doesn't permit the program to build).

If you swap `std::initializer_list` for `int` it all works as expected.

I have reported this issue to Microsoft. *(Will add link when available)*

Comment: [It's not the first time crazy sh!t like this has happened.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/474633/error-c2512-is-incorrectly-triggered.html)